# How to find out if a wallet (an address) contains a token from a contract using web3js?

Tags: contract-development, web3j

Is this possible with and without knowing the private key of the wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this...

```
function getBalanceOf(tokenAddress, walletAddress) {

// The minimum ABI to get ERC20 Token balance
let minABI = [
  // balanceOf
  {
    "constant":true,
    "inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],
    "name":"balanceOf",
    "outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],
    "type":"function"
  },
  // decimals
  {
    "constant":true,
    "inputs":[],
    "name":"decimals",
    "outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],
    "type":"function"
  }
];

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/placeyourAPIkeyhere"));
    }

// Get ERC20 Token contract instance
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, tokenAddress);

// Call balanceOf function
contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call().then(function (result) {

//Do something that you want here when you get a result/balance

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is possible.  Something like this:

```solidity
var tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract([
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_owner",
        "type": "address"
      }
    ],
    "name": "balanceOf",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "balance",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  }], '0x<address of token contract>');
var balance = tokenContract.methods.balanceOf.call ('0x<address of token holder>');
```